# UITextView Resize - Large Text cutted of from landscape to portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a question regarding the resizing of a `UITextView`. I have a textview that reside inside a `UIView` container. When the application starts, the container, only displays the toolbar and when the user tap on it, the `UIView` of the textview is added as a subview of the container and the text is displayed. When the user taps again on the toolbar, the view of the `UITextView` is removed from its superview (The container), and so on.
Every time I need to resize my textview, I calculate it's dimension using the following code and logging the value, they are right.

```
  CGSize size = [stringToUse  sizeWithFont:[self.synthesisTextView font]
                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(synthesisTextViewBounds.size.width, FLT_MAX)
                        lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    [self.synthesisTextView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [self.synthesisTextView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(synthesisTextViewBounds.size.width,
                                                      size.height + 50)];

    [self.synthesisTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(synthesisTextViewFrame.origin.x,
                                                synthesisTextViewFrame.origin.y,
                                                synthesisTextViewBounds.size.width,
                                                size.height + 50)];

    [self.synthesisLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(self.synthesisLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                             self.synthesisLabel.frame.origin.y,
                                             self.synthesisLabel.frame.size.width,
                                             size.height + 50)];
```

There is a particular case in which the text is cut off, even if the `UITextView` has the right dimension.

Here are the steps that I perform:

1. I open the application in lanscape and I can see the toolbar.
2. I tap the toolbar, I calculate the textview size and I add it as a
   subview of the container and then resize it. (Here the dimension are
   right).
3. I rotate the device, The textview is resized (The dimension are
   right) - LANDSCAPE!!
4. I tap the toolbar again to close the container. I remove the
   `UITextView` from the container and then resize it.
5. I tap again the toolbar. The textview is added as subview of the
   container and have right dimension (LANDSCAPE).
6. I rotate the device in PORTRAIT. The textview dimension are
   calculated right, but the text result cut off.

How can I solve my situation?

Thanks a lot!!

Ciao!!

Answer (score 0):

```
//textView Height as per content

CGRect frame = viewNote.frame;
NSLog(@"Text Size height : %f",frame.size.height);

CGSize textViewSize;
if (isIPhone) {
    textViewSize = [viewNote.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]
                                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(309, 10000)
                                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
}else{
    textViewSize = [viewNote.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:30]
                                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(768, 10000)
                                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
}

frame.size.height = textViewSize.height;
viewNote.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Thanks mohitpopat, I've tried whit your implementation but unfortunatelly does work as mine. The width of the textview is always correct. There is only a case in which the textview does not display correctly the text and cut it